# Cannot unpause a Zap ending with a search in zapier?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have created a zap which get file name from dropbox & send it to an API call, this api creates item on sever & then i call another api which search for item by itemid.

so steps are

1. Get item name from dropbox(Used dropbox zap)
2. Create an item on server (Use create of zap)
3. Search for item with item id which is crated by step 2.

But i am getting below error when i try to run the zap.
Cannot unpause a Zap ending with a search

> Cannot unpause a Zap ending with a search

Can anyone explain why it is happening ?

Comment: The filter works by filtering to go to the next step. I thought it was the last step to avoid the whole process to happen. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the purpose of a search step is to find data, Zapier considers it an error if it tries to find something and you don't do anything with that data. Your options are:

1. add a 4th step, probably something that uses the item id from step 3
2. remove the search step
3. Turn the search into a search or create (though that's not helpful here, since you literally just created the item)